# Is it allowed to ask questions about the content of a SE portfolio?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have several questions about the content and requirements of a software engineer portfolio. For example:

- What kind of code examples are interesting?
- Which content is expected from a student applying for programming job?
- Is it a good idea to provide (very) long comments to your code?
- How to properly present projects, when the "outcome" is nice, but the code isn't?
- Some more ;)

Is it allowed to ask a question containing some of the questions above?
Or will this be off-topic/to broad/primarily opinion based?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are Career-Advice Questions On-Topic Here?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8206/are-career-advice-questions-on-topic-here)

Answer (score 3):

These types of questions would be off-topic. They all appear to be primarily opinion based. Building a portfolio is also a career development subject, which is also off-topic here.